# Imagick PHP Exception 1630 on Chrome: Read exception

Tags: php, imagick

I have trouble resolving an issue with Imagick (php version of imagemagick) while generating a new image.

1. I retrieve my image via a $_POST
2. I convert the string with base64
3. I stock in on the server
4. I generate a new Imagick() with the newly created image

Weirdly, the script works perfectly fine on Firefox + IE (a new image is generated) but it generates a fatalerror on Googgle Chrome (desktop + mobile):

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Read
>   Exception `MYSERVERPATH/10562112e9c44d0.png' @
>   error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1630' in MYSERVERPATH/result.php:41
>   Stack trace: #0
>
> MYSERVERPATH/result.php(41):
>   Imagick->__construct('/httpdjail/var/...') #1 {main} thrown in
>   MYSERVERPATH/result.php on line 41

My line 41 is:
$image = new Imagick(MY SERVER PATH. $file);

I'm quite new at coding PHP, then any help would be very appreciated :).

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> I retrieve my image via a $_POST

This feels very bad,

Your error seems to hint at `MYSERVERPATH` is not getting converted to the string that you should have in there hence imagemagik doesn't know where it is hence errors out.

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for your reply.
It definitely comes from the $_POST since my pic seems partially truncated(there's a transparent part on the image generated). How can I fix that? 

Is there a way to avoid sending my image through a super long base64 string (and makes sure that the image is not cropped)..?

Comment: There are occasions where it comes through as a $_POST but that's when it's been generated via javascript? Alright if it is coming through as $_POST - you can check it out by echoing the string and then put the string in the url bar in say chrome. I think as well you can do `<img src="'.$_POST['mystring'].'"/>` and it should appear. That will check if the url is ok or not.